# How to set x_lim and y_lim on my figure? [Python 2.7 matplotlib]

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some troubles with plotting the figure. I have a file with some results computed by application I wrote in c++ and I would like to plot the figure for the computed data.

The problem is that I don't know the 'max' and 'min' limit on axis X and axis Y ...

I tried:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_it(ox, oy, x_label, y_label, filename) :

    fig = plt.figure()
    axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.xlabel(x_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_label)
    plt.ylim(min(oy),max(oy))
    plt.xlim(min(ox),max(ox))
    axis.plot(ox, oy, color = 'red')
    plt.savefig(filename)
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()

filename = input("Filename (file with data)\n>")
res = []
try :
    with open(filename, 'r') as file :
        for line in file :
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            res.append(line.split(" "))
except IOError :
    print("IO error")

if len(res) != 0 :

    ox = []
    oy = []

    x_label = str(input("OX label\n>"))
    y_label = str(input("OY label\n>"))

    for i in range(0,len(res)) :
        ox.append(res[i][0])
        oy.append(res[i][1])

    plot_it(ox, oy, x_label, y_label, 'fig_' + str(filename[:len(filename)-4]) + '.png')
```

Where my file is here: http://pastie.org/private/4rl64ule9ymljmp6g5bfzg (just copy it and save as file.txt)

I got those errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:/plotter.py", line 43, in
>   
>       plot_it(ox, oy, x_label, y_label, 'fig_' + str(filename[:len(filename)-4]) + '.png')   File "E:/plotter.py", line
>   14, in plot_it
>       plt.ylim(min(oy),max(oy))   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1252, in
>   ylim
>       ret = ax.set_ylim(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 2642, in
>   set_ylim
>       bottom, top = mtransforms.nonsingular(bottom, top, increasing=False)   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 2282,
>   in nonsingular
>       if (not np.isfinite(vmin)) or (not np.isfinite(vmax)): NotImplementedError: Not implemented for this type

Comment: Its not clear exactly what the problem was in the first place, whether its been fixed, and whether the suggestions so far have been a help or not. It also seems that you have updated your code based on some answers which makes following the original problem a lot harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
plt.ylim(min(oy),max(oy))
plt.xlim(min(ox),max(ox))
```

to the second block of code you give, this will set your x and limits to the min/max of your data.

Comment: Use `plt.xlim`, not `plt.set_xlim`.

Comment: @Jdog : I got this after adding those lines to my code: http://pastie.org/private/qcltokztdpaiifbvl2anww

Comment: @Chris: see this: http://pastie.org/private/qcltokztdpaiifbvl2anww I used plt.xlim and it didn't help at all :(

Comment: You need to give us some context here - show the whole code and errors, update your question if needed. Also, don't delete previous comments, since this makes the comment thread difficult to follow (what is my first comment refering to now, for example?).

Comment: In your first block of code in the question, replacing `os.set_xlim(min(ox), max(ox))` with `plt.xlim(min(ox), max(ox))` (and similarly for the y axis) works for me. What happens when you try this - update your question if you need to.

Comment: You've updated your code in your question, and the problem isn't there now. This isn't great for future viewers who may have had your problem and are trying to follow the solution by readin question then answers. i.e. The problem in the attempted solution is no longer there, making it confusing.

Comment: @Jdog : yes, I'm sorry. I will remember not to this in the future. But I think the problem is almost the same here because I got errors where definitely plt.xlim is the issue